# How to change the DEFAULT 'page color' for all new messages in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want to change the DEFAULT 'page color' for all new messages in Outlook, from white to light grey.

I found **[Change a theme and make it the default in Outlook or Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-outlook-or-access-21475188-4ea4-4428-8d94-3f1fc5cddef1)** on Microsoft ... which oddly enough does not mention anything about "making it the default".

I don't really need a theme, I just want to change default **Page Color**.

I was on with MS support for nearly an hour and they haven't got a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I noticed that you only want to apply light gray to the new email background. It's suggestted that you could try to create a custom theme and apply it to your outlook client. Please refer to the following for specific operation steps:

1. Create a new message and set the background (New messages > Options > Page color > choose light grey);
2. File > Save as;
3. In the Save As dialog box address bar, enter **`%appdata%\microsoft\stationery`**, and then press Enter;
   [image]
4. The Stationery folder opens, In the File name box, enter a name for your new stationery and In the Save as type list, click **HTML**;
   [image]
5. Click Save;
6. The message can be discarded after these steps are completed；
7. File > Options > Mail > Stationery and Fonts;
8. On the Personal Stationery tab, click Theme;
9. Under Choose a theme, click the theme or stationery that you created, and then click OK;

Then the next time you create a new message, it will have a light gray background by default. Hope to help you!